# Checkmarx Unchecked Input Loop from ServletRequest Input Stream

Tags: java, spring, checkmarx

As part of an `HttpServletRequestWrapper`, I am accessing the input stream of the request content. Checkmarx is flagging this as Unchecked Input for Loop Condition, since the input stream is read using a while loop.

Checkmarx requires some validation on the input stream before it can be used in a loop - I've tried reading the input stream into a byte array and validate the array instead, but the flag is still raised on the input stream itself.

Here's how I'm accessing the input stream:

```
InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream(); //this line is flagged by checkmarx
if (inputStream != null) {
   bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
   char[] charBuffer = new char[128];
   int bytesRead = -1;

   //while loop that reads an unchecked
   while ((bytesRead = bufferedReader.read(charBuffer)) > 0) {
      stringBuilder.append(charBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
   }
}
```

Of course there's no way to verify the length of the input stream before reading it, so how can I validate this input to pass checkmarx?

The checkmarx flag in question:

> `RequestWrapper` gets user input from element `getInputStream`.
> This element’s value flows through the code without being validated,
> and is eventually used in a loop condition in `RequestWrapper` at line 31 of `RequestWrapper.java`.
> This constitutes an *Unchecked Input for Loop Condition*.

Comment: Can you please add the *Checkmarx* error description

Comment: Added the checkmarx error @baruchiro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a case of the `Unchecked_Input_for_Loop_Condition` not recognizing [Definite Assignment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-16.html) used as part of the loop validation criteria.  On digging into the query, it has a comment that code like `(stream.read() != -1)` is a valid checking method, which is similar to your code.

The query needs to be fixed, but in the meantime you have a few options:

1. Mark the vulnerability as `Not Exploitable`
2. Reform your code to not have the definite assignment in the loop condition.  This code, for example, does not trigger the result:

```
do
{
    if ((bytesRead = bufferedReader.read(charBuffer) > 0)
      stringBuilder.append(charBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
} while (bytesRead > 0);
```

Comment: My request processing implementation ended up being changed altogether, but otherwise was planning for option 1 - thanks for the info! option 2 would have been good as well.